# Print does not print background image. While taking screenshot it is shorter, the page is shorter than A4

Tags: html, css

I created a resume in html/css. It renders perfectly on the browser but while taking the print out, it does not print background colors, and change the alignment of the elements as well.

So I took the snapshot to convert in jpeg, but while taking the print out of the image, it renders in the center of the page leaving some space on both ends.

Here is my snippet

```css
:root {
      --font-color: #FFF;
      --section-bg: #424242;
      --info-head: #00B8D4;
      --border-color: #00B8D4;
      --progress-bar: #00B8D4;
      }



      @font-face {
          font-family: FontAwesome;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-style : normal;
                 src : url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
                 src : url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
                       url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
                       url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
                       url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
                       url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
      }
      h5 {
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
      .name p {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      .body {
        background-color: #ccc;
      }
      .container {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 970px;
      }
      .content {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .section {
        background-color: var(--section-bg);
        padding-top: 40px;
      }
      .pic {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100px;
      }
      .name {
        color: var(--font-color);
        margin-bottom: 70px;
      }
      .info-header {
        color: var(--info-head);
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      .info-block {
        text-align: left;
        margin: 102px 0px;
        padding: 10px 0px;
        border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
        border-left: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      .block-part {
        color: var(--font-color);
        margin: 10px 0px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      .icon {
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .progress {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        height: 5px;
      }
      .progress-bar {
        background-color: var(--progress-bar);
      }
      .block-interest {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .hobbies {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .hobbies-icon {
        font-size: 24px;
      }
      .main-content {
        padding-top: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 40px;
      }
      .main-content-header {
        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        color: var(--info-head);
      }
      .work-comp {
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
      .work-desc {
        color: #757575;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
      .list-complete {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
      }
      .list-complete ::before {
        content: "\f121";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px;
        left: -37px;
        color: var(--progress-bar);
      }
      .list-item {
        border-left: 1px dotted var(--progress-bar);;
        padding-left: 30px;
        position: relative;
      }
      .list-item ::before {
        content: "";
      }
      .list-item-last {
        border: none;
      }
      .work-content {
        top: -30px;
        position: relative;
      }
      .edu {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
      .filled-icon {
        color: var(--progress-bar);
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      .unfilled-icon {
        color: var(--progress-bar);
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      .skill-row {
        padding-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      .skill-star {
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      .achievement {
        margin-top: 15px;
      }
```

```html
<body class = "body">
    <div class = "container" id = "container">
      <div class = "row" id = "row-container">
        <div class = "col-sm-12 content">
          <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-3 section">
              <div class = "profile-pic">
                <img class = "pic" src = "./me.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class = "name">
                <h5>ISHAN GUPTA</h5>
                <p>
                  Web Developer
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class = "info-header">
                INFO
              </div>
              <div class = "info-block">
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt icon"></i>
                  <span>Andheri East, Mumbai, India</span>
                </div>
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <i class="fas fa-phone icon"></i>
                  <span>+91 8603561265</span>
                </div>
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <i class="fas fa-envelope icon"></i>
                  <span>mrishan1993@gmail.com</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "info-header">
                INTERESTS
              </div>
              <div class = "info-block">
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <div class = "block-interest">
                    <i class="fas fa-lightbulb icon"></i>
                    Entrepreneurship
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <div class = "block-interest">
                    <i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt icon"></i>
                    Microeconomics
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:75%">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <div class = "block-interest">
                    <i class="fab fa-bitcoin icon"></i>
                    Blockchain
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "block-part">
                  <div class = "block-interest">
                    <i class="fa fa-universal-access icon"></i>
                    Augmented Reality
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "info-header">
                HOBBIES
              </div>
              <div class = "info-block">
                <div class = "row block-part hobbies">
                  <div class = "col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-film icon hobbies-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class = "col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-plane icon hobbies-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class = "col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-music icon hobbies-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class = "col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-book icon hobbies-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-9 main-content">
              <div class = "row main-content-header">
                <div class = "col-sm-12">
                  <i class="fas fa-briefcase icon main-icon"></i>
                  WORK EXPERIENCE
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul class = "list-complete">
                <li class = "list-item">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        Servify
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        March '17 - Today
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Developed a Parts Management System on React + Redux with the functionality of raising and fulfilling orders, along with creating new parts. Support of billing and inventory were integrated.
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Owner of CRM on Riot.js with the functionality of raising service request, fulfilment, customer management, logisitcs mangement, and other related operational functions.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "list-item">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        MAQ Software
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        Sept '16 - March '17
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Developed a ChatBot using LUIS AI application which replies back with the corresponding reports of the query asked by the end user.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "list-item list-item-last">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        Independent Work
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Developed a React Native + Redux mobile application which showcases the comics and micro tales of a particular content creator.
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Developed a React + Redux application that enables the user to upload images to S3 and visualises the analytics using Chart.js
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class = "row main-content-header">
                <div class = "col-sm-12">
                  <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap icon main-icon edu"></i>
                  EDUCATION
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul class = "list-complete">
                <li class = "list-item">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        National Institute of Technology, Patna
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        2012-2016, B.Tech, Computer Science and Engineering.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "list-item">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        Agra Public School, Agra
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        2009-2011
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "list-item list-item-last">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        Delhi Public School, Agra
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        2004-2009
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class = "row main-content-header">
                <div class = "col-sm-12">
                  <i class="fas fa-balance-scale icon main-icon edu"></i>
                  SKILLS
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "row skill-row">
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <div class = "work-comp">
                    React + Redux
                  </div>
                  <div class = "skill-star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <div class = "work-comp">
                    Riot
                  </div>
                  <div class = "skill-star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <div class = "work-comp">
                    React Native
                  </div>
                  <div class = "skill-star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "row skill-row">
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <div class = "work-comp">
                    Node
                  </div>
                  <div class = "skill-star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <div class = "work-comp">
                    HTML & CSS
                  </div>
                  <div class = "skill-star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-sm-4">
                  <div class = "work-comp">
                    Platform (DevOps)
                  </div>
                  <div class = "skill-star">
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star filled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star unfilled-icon"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "row main-content-header achievement">
                <div class = "col-sm-12">
                  <i class="fas fa-trophy icon main-icon edu"></i>
                  ACHIEVEMENTS
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul class = "list-complete">
                <li class = "list-item">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        Parallel World, Offcial magazine of NIT Patna
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Student Head
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "list-item">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        National Cyber Olympiad, 2005
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Bronze Medallist
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "list-item list-item-last">
                  <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-sm-12 work-content">
                      <p class = "work-comp">
                        National Science Olympiad, 2007
                      </p>
                      <p class = "work-desc">
                        Bronze Medallist
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6G1Y.png]

On The Print Dialogue

1. Click More Settings
2. Tick Background graphics

­          ­­  ­          ­­  ­          ­­

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19600389)

Comment: Just Did Thanks for the heads up.